# How I can add one floor, one row and one extra columns ´to my existing array containing data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensor

I want to add one floor, one row and one columns into my existing  3-D matrix without losing the original information from the matrix

```
import numpy as np
tensor = np.zeros((len(subjects), len(properties) , len(objects)))
#subjects are 4, properties are 5 and objects are 7 in my case.
print(tensor.shape)
(4, 5, 7)
```

so I need to add one on more floor, row and columns, so it will give me the following output

```
so it will give me 
print(tensor.shape)
(5,6,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) is your friend.

```py
>>> tensor = np.pad(tensor, (0,1), 'constant')
>>> tensor.shape
(5,6,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's [insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) function should help you here. Using the `axis` parameter helps to change which dimension/axis you are inserting into.

```
print(np.insert(tensor, 0, 0, axis=0).shape)
(5,5,7)

print(np.insert(tensor, 0, 0, axis=1).shape)
(4,6,7)

print(np.insert(tensor, 0, 0, axis=2).shape)
(4,5,8)
```

So if you need to do these inserts one at a time, this could be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

In each insert a column or row or height is added:

```
tensor = np.zeros((4, 5 , 6))
tensor=np.insert(tensor,[4],tensor[1,:,:],axis=0)
tensor=np.insert(tensor,[5],tensor[1,1,:],axis=1)
tensor=np.insert(tensor,[6],[0],axis=2)
print(tensor.shape)
```

> Output: (5, 6, 7)